# Python change the starting values on the plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, scikit-learn, visualization

I have data set which looks like this:

```
Hour_day   Profits
  7          645
  3          354
  5          346
  11         153
  23         478
  7          464
  12         356
  0          346
```

I crated a line plot to visualize the hour on the x-axis and the profit values on y-axis. My code worked good with me but the problem is that on the x-axis it started at 0. but I want to start from 5 pm for example.

```
hours = df.Hour_day.value_counts().keys()
hours = hours.sort_values() 

# Get plot information from actual data
y_values = list()
for hr in hours:
    temp = df[df.Hour_day == hr]
    y_values.append(temp.Profits.mean())
    
# Plot comparison
plt.plot(hours, y_values, color='y')
```

[image]

Comment: But you have a 0 in your data.. Do you just not want to show that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you have two options:

Create a sub DF that excludes the rows that have an Hour_day value under 5 and proceed with the rest of your code as normal:

```
df_new = df.where(df['Hour_day'] >= 5)
```

or, you might be able to set the x_ticks:

```
default_x_ticks = range(5:23)
plt.plot(hours, y_values, color='y')
plt.xticks(default_x_ticks, hours)
plt.show()
```

I haven't tested the x_ticks code so you might have to play around with it just a touch, but there are lots of easy to find resources on x_ticks.